# Correct way to permit strong parameters for nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have model named note.rb as follows:

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :tags
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

And also a model named tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :note
end
```

The form for new note creation is as follows:

```
<%= form_with scope: :note, url: notes_path, local: true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
    <%= f.fields_for :tags_attributes do |t| %>
    <p>
      <%= label_tag(:name, "Add a tag") %><br>
      <%= t.text_field :name %>

    </p>    

    <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<div id= "tag-displayer">
   <span id= "tags"></span>
</div>
```

I am trying create a record for tag with a record of note.

In my notes_controller.rb I have

```
def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params) 
    @note.user = current_user
    if @note.save 
      redirect_to '/notes'
    else 
      render 'new' 
    end         
end
```

and :

```
private
  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :description, tags_attributes: [:id, :name])
  end
```

Now on form submit I get the following:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
```

I get the same error if I use:

```
params.require(:note).permit(:title, :description, :tags_attributes => [:id, :name])
```

I get the error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :tags_attributes
```

If I use:

```
params.require(:note).permit(:title, :description, :tags_attributes => [])
```

Params for form submit:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iSsLyOb0ZxZP0rfB4I5yfyrw965zJSLrtkroTUzseY2k4o5DwKpKXlyxN6p99pt4Fwju1RhMZPkbNdv+YVSESQ==", "note"=>{"title"=>"test note with Tag", "description"=>"Test note with tag", "tags_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Rails"}}, "commit"=>"Save Note"}
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried all possible solutions available to me.

Using Rails 5 with ruby 2.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue is that your form is passing:

```
{..., "tags_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Rails"}}, ...}
```

When it needs to pass:

```
{..., "tags_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"Rails"}], ...}  # The hash is inside an array.
```

Or possibly:

```
{..., "tags_attributes"=>{"any_key_except_id" => {"name"=>"Rails"}}, ...}
```

I'm pretty sure the `TypeError` is coming from that issue, probably that at some point it's trying to treat the string `"Rails"` as a hash and tries to call `"Rails"[:id]` on it.

My hunch (without reproducing your entire setup) is that this can be solved by changing your line that says:

```
    <%= f.fields_for :tags_attributes do |t| %>
```

to

```
    <%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
```

If you look at the [documentation for `fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), it uses the name of the association, without the `_attributes` at the end. With `:tags_attributes`, I think the form doesn't know what to do with it, assumes it's a single item instead of a collection, and so doesn't nest the attributes in an array.

Note that if you want to have it display the field for a new tag (instead of just existing tags), I believe you'll have to call `@note.tags.build` somewhere before the `fields_for` call so that there's an unsaved `Tag` entity in the `tags` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I look at your params, you actually do have strings. There are several ways to fix that, but the most straightforward way in my opinion is just to permit strings instead of symbols. For tags_attributes, that should be 'tags_attributes' => ..., for the rest I'm not sure if I remember correctly: it's either 'title' or :'title', probably the latter. I think the same goes for 'note' or :'note'. I hope you can just play around a bit and see which one it is. I had the error before, so I'm quite certain that should fix it. I hope I can help! Please let me know which one fixes it, I'm curious to know :)

Comment: Sorry that I'm not completely certain, I'm still learning myself. I hope I can help anyway

Comment: Can you give me the full error message with stack trace? and line number?

Comment: Rails by default converts params using HashWithIndifferentAccess. So, all the string keys can be accessed via their corresponding symbols. Eg: `params[:tag_attributes][:name]` will return "rails" and not nil. Hence there is no need to add strings instead of symbols in Strong parameters

Answer (score 0):

Well i think  you don't need to add id in strong parameters

try this: -

```
params.require(:note).permit(:title, :description, tags_attributes: [:name])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your model declaring `has_many :tags` and your form data coming in as an object `:tags_attributes => {id: "", name: ""}`.

The `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):` error could be bubbling up when you are trying trying to save the note `@note.save` or when you are initialising it using `@note = Note.new(note_params)` but not because of Strong parameters. Strong parameters should permit those parameters because the definition matches the form data you are sending.

Try modifying the frontend to send tags in an array format like `:tags_attributes => [{id: "", name: ""}, {id: "", name: ""}]`

There is blog that is almost if not exact similar to the problem you are facing, check it out http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/29/rails-tricky-error-no-implicit-conversion-from-symbol-to-integer/